# 2010 White MacBook won't shut down; restarts instead

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, shutdown, restart

I have ave a 2010 White MacBook 7,1 Core2Duo; bought used.  I installed a previously unused HDD.  I increased the memory to 4GB RAM.  There are only three non-Apple apps, Citrix, Dropbox, Opera.  It was working perfectly.

Now it  mysteriously began to always restart after telling it to shutdown.  This happens using the Apple menu, using the logout menu, or using `sudo halt` or `sudo shutdown -h now` in Terminal.  The only way to successfully turn it off and have it stay off is <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⦿ Power</kbd> which seems to work.

- Disk utility says no problem. Apple hardware diagnostics say noproblem.
- Multiple NVRAM zaps ineffective. Multiple SMC resets ineffective.
- Tried different power supplies.  Tried disconnected and connected.
- Tried leaving the lid up, tried closing it quickly.
- Tried deleting user and making a new primary admin user.
- Tried starting and turning off every single program in case something had been left hanging.
- Deleted Dropbox and Citrix.
- Disabled auto logon.  Enabled it again.

Nothing works.

This laptop literally only needs to do four things—turn on, check email, check a single Numbers spreadsheet, turn back off—for my mom who is older and not tech savvy at all.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Other than starting in Safe Mode (power on holding SHIFT till you see the Apple logo) you have done everything in software you can. This is an **old** MacBook. Swap out any hardware you replaced and see if that changes its behavior. If not well it may be dying...

Comment: Your MacBook supports Internet Recovery (assuming you did the firmware upgrade).  Press `cmd-opt-r` and boot into Recovery, then using Terminal, try shutting down `shutdown -h now`.  If it reboots, you have a hardware issue.